# How can I add back to previous page on webview fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-webview, back

I have an android app created with android studio that has a main activity and fragments with webview. Each fragment contains webview code with a link to a website. The problem that I have is that when I press back it closes the app. I want to use back to go to the previous page and the previous activity.
Main Activity code:

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_facebook:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new FacebookFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_twitter:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new TwitterFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_instagram:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new InstagramFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_linkedin:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new LinkedinFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_snapchat:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SnapchatFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_pinterest:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new PinterestFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_youtube:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new YoutubeFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_about:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new AboutFragment()).commit();
            break;
        case R.id.nav_privacy:
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new PrivacyFragment()).commit();
            break;
    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Here is the code of one of the fragment's code (the rest of the fragments has similar code):

```
public class FacebookFragment extends Fragment {
    public FacebookFragment() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);
        WebView webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com/");
        return v;

    }

    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the fragment just make sure to add it to back stack using:

```
replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new YoutubeFragment()).addToBackStack("tag").commit()
```

and override the onBackPressed function to pop up stack while it's not empty.

Comment: Where should I replace the fragment? On the Main Activity or on the fragment activity?

Comment: same as your code, when the item get selected you are doing this:

 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new YoutubeFragment()).commit();

but instead do this:
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new YoutubeFragment()).addToBackStack("tag").commit()

and then override onBackPressed to popup the stack

Comment: Hello. I add the code that you told me but I am not sure about the override onBackPressed to popup the stack.  Can you tell me exactly what to do, I am not as good as you with Java. With the current onBackPressed it goes back to the previous activity but it doesn't go back pages on the fragment activity.

Comment: do the following:

@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            fm.popBackStack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

Comment: I changed the override onBackPresse() code and I still have the same problem, it goes back to the previous fragment activity but it doesn't go to a previous page on a fragment activity.

Comment: then I think you have a logical problem in your code because adding to back stack and pop up from stack is the correct way to do it.
try to debug your code and see what have you missed in implementation.

Comment: if it's still not clear you better move to Navigation UI component it facilities this work

Comment: I had assumed that I need it a onBackPressed that mentioned webview since the activities that don't go back have webview.  Can you help me with the debug? I copied the debugging to a file on https://www.urbantutorial.com/support/debug-kubula.txt .

Answer (score 0):

All these fragments have same function is go back fragment. Why don't add the base fragment for them and the code will be easier.

Comment: Abd Alrhman Bazrto (the other person who answered) has helped me, it doesn't close anymore when I press back. However it has a problem, it goes back to the previous activity but not pages back on the fragment with webview. I am just a beguiner, not sure how to apply the solution that you suggested. Can you help me? I want the end result to have webview in separate fragment activities because I need it for indexing the app, to be properly indexed each link must be on a different activity.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.  I see you have a switch case  statement. If you have a BaseFragment (it is superclass of  FacebookFragment, TwitterFragment, InstagramFragment, LinkedinFragment,  SnapchatFragment, PinterestFragment, YoutubeFragment, AboutFragment, PrivacyFragment). BaseFragment has back() method to back to previous fragment. Each child classes will implement this method. Your implementation MenuItem class have reference to BaseFragment.
Now your switch case turns into item.getFragment().back(). This approach is good when you add other fragment, you don't need change your code.